# Compute $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

How would you go about calculating the sum 
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n3^n}$$

The solution is apparently $\log(\frac32)$ but I'm not sure how one would calculate it since the Taylor expansion for $\log(1+x)$ is $\displaystyle\sum(-1)^{n-1}x^n/n$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, we have $\sum_n \frac{n}{3^n}=\frac{3}{4}$, but you wrote the $n$ below - a typo?

Comment: Perhaps consider $\log(1-x)$ instead

Comment: Even better, $$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

Comment: ((Erased `weird` in the title, that was... well, weird.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|x|<1$, consider:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
Integrate it:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\ln{(1-x)} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}=\ln{\frac{1}{1-x}}.$$
Now plug $x=\frac13$ to get:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac13\right)^n}{n} = \ln{\frac{1}{1-\frac13}}=\ln{\frac32}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Not that weird: 
$$\log(1-x)=-\Bigl( x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dotsm\Bigr),$$
so the answer is $-\log(1-x)=\log\dfrac1{1-x}$ for $x=\dfrac13$.